# Why is my file size shown as Zero bytes in Mac Finder?

Tags: mac, finder

I have OS X El Capitan Version 10.11.6 (15G31). I have a file with contents in it, but Finder shows that the file is Zero bytes?!?

What does this mean? How can the file be zero bytes if there is clearly something in the file?

I can see that the file is not empty by opening it with any text editor, or if I make a copy of the file it's now 1KB.

Also, if I 'cd' into that folder using the terminal (aka command line) then it shows the file size as it should be.

What could possibly be going on here?

Comment: Turns out, the same thing happens on Windows. It must be the application creating the file.

Comment: If you want a real shock, search in the Finder for files of 0 (zero) KB size. Mine, 905 including documents created 10-Dec-2018 and as far back as 1995.

Comment: I know this is waaay after the fact, but how could an application fool the operating system about a file's size? It seems to be the case (happens for me with Gimp), but I'm curious about how.

Answer (score 2):

It could be filesystem data structure corruption. Use Disk Utility to run a First Aid repair pass on that volume.

Comment: It's weird it's just the one file. Maybe it's the application creating the file. It's a log file spit out using log4j from a Java application.

Comment: The weird thing is that this application generates other log file without this issue and other types of files in other places with no issue.

Answer (score 0):

I find that in the OSX Mail library, there can be many many directories and sub directories which are labelled "Zero bytes", yet contain other subdirectories, also labelled "Zero bytes". Yet clicking on one of these subdirectories updates the size of the parent to a nonzero value, typically a few KB. This is a pervasive behavior in my instance where re-indexing the Mail library (by removing all envelope index files, and rre-starting Mail) creates voluminous ".noindex" directory structures.  Repeating the re-indexing do not help, and seems to generate more and more such ",noindex" directories, which contain "Zero-byte" subdirectories and files, yet occupy enormous space.  My Mail library is now 1.82 TB (really!) and seems to be beyond repair.  (running BIG SUR 11.6 on an  iMac Pro -2017 with 4 TB SSD).

I extracted copies of two instances of such subdirectories (C66D0677-CDA6-46A6-8AB7-EAE909A07B9F,and C66D0677-CDA6-46A6-8AB7-EAE909A07B9F.noindex) which seem to contain the same few .emlx files but also many "zero-byte" subdirectories -- substantially more  for the .noindex version. I selected those because they were small enough to explore amd fool around with the finder. The have exactly the same names except for the .noindex suffix. I cn find many more examples in the Mail Library, some of which are huge.  I can provide these two directories to anyone who might want to duplicate my efforts (about 74 KB Zip file).  Bernard

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://superuser.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1082890)

Answer (score 0):

today I had this happen with a folder:

- the folder clearly had contents in it
- I could list the contents of the folder using a terminal command
- when I tried to navigate into the folder to open a file inside it the folder appeared with a red minus icon in the finder window and a size of zero bytes

I finally noticed that I had another application (jebrains intellij in this case) which had that folder locked due to a modal rename dialog which I had opened and failed to close.

Once I closed that dialog the folder once again appeared normal in the finder window.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I have the same with files on a cloud (one-drive) out of 68 photos only one can be opened, the rest gives me a 'no permission' and whilst the file is 4 mb, it says 'zero bytes on disk'
Could anyone advise me what to do?

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://superuser.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1160509)